# What are best practices using AWS Cognito to authenticate a REST API

Tags: rest, authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito

I'm building a REST API and using AWS Cognito's user pools for authentication. I've got a "get_token" endpoint that returns the JWT access and refresh tokens to the user, which they use to authenticate access to the other REST endpoints provided by the API.

The access token has an expiration timeout. If the user of my API is an application program, what are the best practices for the application to handle when the access token expires? Does the application have to remember the username/password and re-authenticate to continue? Is using the refresh token to get a new access token and use that going forward the best approach?

Is there any documentation, suggestions anyone can point out that might help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito provides 3 types of tokens, `id`, `access` and `refresh` tokens when you login. The way this usually works is that you send either of the first two (depends on whether you want to be sending user payload information to your backend) to your backend via an `Authorization` header and verify the token there.

Your `id` and `access` tokens usually have a shorter expiration time compared to the `refresh` token. What you should do is, when the `id` (or `access`) token expire, you should use the `refresh` token to generate a new `id` (or `access`) token. When the `refresh` token expires that means that you can no longer generate new `id/access` tokens from it. In this case, the user (or app) must login again.

Comment: That all sounds reasonable and what I expect from having used the Cognito interface. Regarding using it with a REST API, should this be handled by the REST API application or by the user application using the REST API? I'm thinking it should be the user, but want to know your thoughts.

Comment: You mean refreshing the tokens? That's the responsibility of the "client" using your REST API. In the backend you only need to verify the token before it reaches your actual business logic (e.g. in some middleware layer). If the token is valid, then execute logic, otherwise throw an exception.